# Ubuntu/UFW: How to tell Docker not to expose all ports?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, port, iptables

I'm really struggling here and googled a lot... no solution worked so far.

I'm running several docker containers (nodejs, mongodb,...) on my Ubuntu machine. Unfortunately, Docker (v1.6) exposes all ports to public! Since I have an nginx reverse proxy (also in a docker container), I only want port 80 to be accessible from outside - UFW does not work in this case, since Docker operates on iptables.

So I tried the following suggestions:

1. Changed DOCKER_OPTS to the following (and restarted docker service):

   ```
   DOCKER_OPTS="--ip 127.0.0.1 --iptables=false"
   ```
2. Added the following rules to my iptables (for nodejs port 3001)

   ```
   iptables -I PREROUTING 1 -t mangle ! -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3001 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I PREROUTING 2 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 3001 -j DROP
   ```

=> both changes do not work?

Are there any other suggestions that might help here?

In short: I only want port 80 (nginx docker container) to be exposed to public... all other (e.g. 3001) should be rejected when not accessed from localhost!

**UPDATE:**

**I forgot to mention that I start the containers with "-p 3001:3000" (e.g. for the nodejs app).**

**I don't want this port (3001) to be accessible from the web... but only from other containers or the docker host system).**

Thank you very much in advance.

Greetz,

Sascha

Comment: "Docker (v1.6) exposes all ports to public": docker exposes no port at all by default.

Comment: unless you start your containers with `--net="host"`

Comment: Thx for your comments... you're right... it does not expose anything by default... but when I start it with -p 3001:3000, then it exposes port 3001... and I couldn't find a way to deny any requests from outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the `-p` from your `docker run` command line.

Container ports will, by default, be available to other containers running on your system without using `-p`.  You just need to know the ip address of the target container.  For example, if I start a web server:

```
$ docker run --name web -d larsks/mini-httpd
```

And get the ip address:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' web
172.17.0.3
```

Then from the host or any other container I can run something like:

```
# curl http://172.17.0.3/
```

I can also use container linking if I don't want to muck around with ip addresses.  For example, if the `web` container above is already running, I can link it to a new container:

```
$ docker run --link web:web -it alpine sh
```

And then access it by name:

```
/ # wget -O- http://web/
<pre>
 ___ _    __        __         _          
|_ _| |_  \ \      / /__  _ __| | _____   
 | || __|  \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ / __|  
 | || |_    \ V  V / (_) | |  |   <\__ \_ 
|___|\__|    \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\_\___(_)

</pre>
```

Comment: Solved it by linking without specifying the port via "-p"... Thank you very much!